# Meteor reactive publish data from different collections

Tags: mongodb, meteor, publish-subscribe, reactive

i try to build a homeautomation system with meteor. therefore i would like to do the following thing.

i have a collection with all my different liveValues i'm reading from any kind of source. each document is a value of a for example sensor with the actual value.

now i want to create a second collection called thing. in this collection i'd like to add all my "Things" for example "Roomtemperature living" with the data for this thing. one attribute should be the connection to one of liveValues.

Now i want to publish and subscribe with Meteor the Thing collection, because on the webinterface it doesn't matter what liveValue is behind the Thing.

Here, the in my optionen, complicated part starts.

How can i publish the data to the client and i will have a reactive update when the LiveValue has changend for the thing? because it's an differnt collection than "Thing" collection.

In my idea i would like to do this via one subscrition to one "thing" document and i will get back with this subscription the update of the liveValue of the liveValue collection.

Is this workable?

has somebody an idea how i can handle this?

i've heard something about [meteor-reactive-publish](https://github.com/peerlibrary/meteor-reactive-publish) but i'not sure if this is the solution. also i've heard that this needs a lots of power for the server.

thanks for your help.

Comment: Have you looked at the [reywood:publish-composite](https://atmospherejs.com/reywood/publish-composite) package? This would be a fairly standard use case for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So basically you want to merge the documents on server side to one reactive collection on client-side.

You should use `observeChanges` provided by Meteor Collections as described in the [docs](https://docs.meteor.com/api/collections.html#Mongo-Cursor-observeChanges).

By this you can observe the changes on your server side collections and publish to your client-side aggregated collection, like this:

```
// Get the data from a kind of sensor
var cursor = SomeSensor.find({/* your query */});

var self = this;

// Observe the changes in the cursor and publish
// it to the 'things' collection in client
var observer = cursor.observeChanges({
  added: function (document) {
    self.added('things', document._id, document);
  },
  removed: function (document) {
    self.removed('things', document._id, document);
  },
  changed: function (document) {
    self.changed('things', document._id, document);
  }
});

// Make the publication ready
self.ready();

// Stop the observer on subscription stop
self.onStop(function () {
  observer.stop();
});
```

With this the `things` collection will have the data from all the sensors reactively.

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Hi. With your Code o observe the Thing collection. But i want to observe the liveValue Collection / document.

Comment: If you see, the cursor I'm observing is from `SomeSensor` collection i.e. your liveValue collection.
It's like `cursor = liveValue.find({})`. We're observing `liveValue` collection and pushing it's documents to `things` collection reactively

Comment: What do you think about this package?
[meteor-publish-composite](https://github.com/englue/meteor-publish-composite). I think this is exactly what i'm searching. or not?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think yes. The package is doing something like what I explained above. [See here](https://github.com/englue/meteor-publish-composite/blob/master/lib/publication.js#L18)

Comment: @PunitGupta Yes, it is pretty central to how publication works under the hoods in Meteor. And the fact that the doc link is not broken, tells me this works.